# argv in C++ clearup

Tags: c++, unix, argv, argc

So I have this assignment(input a string and it will display the number of strings) where I have to explain why the argv[0] value and argv[3] values change. So when you step through the program (my string input is "run how now brown cow" argv[0] starts off as my directory folder ("/home/013/w/wn/%$%$%#%/Assignment4/p2"). And then argv[3] starts off as "now". I don't understand why those variables change whenever the program is running, because the "now" string should be in argv[2], right? Whenever my program compiles the argv[] array corresponds to everything at the end, but why not at the beginning?

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* print a given string and a number in a pre-determined format. */
void
print_string(int num, char* string)
{
    printf("String '%d' - '%s'\n", num, string);
}

int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i;

    /* check for command line arguments */
    if (argc < 2) { /* 2 - 1 for program name (argv[0]) and one for a param. */
       printf("Usage: %s [<string> ...]\n", argv[0]);
        return(1);
    }

    /* loop over all strings, print them one by one */
    for (argc--,argv++,i=0 ; argc > 0; argc--,argv++,i++) {
        print_string(i, argv[0]);  /* function call */
    }

    printf("Total number of strings: %d\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `argv[0]` is the filename used to invoke the program, actual command-line arguments are stored in `argv[1...]`

Comment: @BenVoigt beat me to it

Comment: They change while the program is running because you actually modify your parameters (`argc--,argv++`) which is a style that is generally frowned upon.

Comment: The strings aren't changing...you are changing your own pointer to them (you're advancing the pointer that starts out pointing to argv[0], then after argv++ it points to argv[1], etc.)  As @BenVoight says, this is a confusing style.  Typically, you'd want to do something like `for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) { /* do something with argv[i] */ }`

Comment: Yeah, it was so weird when I saw the structure for the for loop. I guess the Professor just wanted to confuse us lol. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Array indices start at `0` and the first element of `argv` is the path of the executed file, so for example if you execute your binary like this:

```
./test run how now brown cow
```

You will get the following elements in `argv`:

```
argv[0] = "./test"
argv[1] = "run"
argv[2] = "how"
argv[3] = "now"
argv[4] = "brown"
argv[5] = "cow"
```

As you can see, it is totaly right that now is on the 3rd and not on the 2nd element.